# Tab disappeared in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I click tab2, the link showed in the content area should trigger the click effect in Tab3, it works but the tab3 disappears immediately after excecuting the show() method.
I copy the code in this example, I don't know where I did wrong.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEpGK

Any help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").click(function() {
    $('a[rel="tab3"]').trigger("click");
  });
  $("#mtabs li").click(function() {
    $("#mtabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".wrapper-content div").hide();
    var current = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(current).show();
    return;
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 422px;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#mtabs {
  width: 422px;
}
#mtabs ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#mtabs ul li.active {
  background-color: #00f;
}
#mtabs ul li a {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper-content {
  height: 60px;
  width: 237px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.wrapper-content>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div id="mtabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1" rel="tab1">tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" rel="tab2">tab2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" rel="tab3">tab3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-content">
  <div id="tab1">tab1</div>
  <div id="tab2"><a href="" id="link">go to tab3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">tab3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [event.preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to stop the default action of the event click on the

A second solution is to change `href=""` to `href="#"` to prevent it from navigating outside of the page  `<div id="tab2"><a href="#" id="link">go to tab3</a>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('a[rel="tab3"]').trigger("click");
  });
  $("#mtabs li").click(function() {
    $("#mtabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".wrapper-content div").hide();
    var current = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(current).show();
    return;
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 422px;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#mtabs {
  width: 422px;
}
#mtabs ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#mtabs ul li.active {
  background-color: #00f;
}
#mtabs ul li a {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper-content {
  height: 60px;
  width: 237px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.wrapper-content>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div id="mtabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab1" rel="tab1">tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" rel="tab2">tab2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" rel="tab3">tab3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-content">
  <div id="tab1">tab1</div>
  <div id="tab2"><a href="" id="link">go to tab3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">tab3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works,but what do you mean by "default action of the event click on the ...", and the "navigating outside of the page" in the second choice is the reason why it disappears? how does that happen, could you explain a little bit more in detail?

Comment: The <a> tag defines a hyperlink, When you click on it it will take you to an other page, <a href="#id"> will take take to the element that has that id in the same page.